# Is it possible to fetch LDAP fields and store them in a SQL database?

Tags: c#, sql, ldap

I've got LDAP authentication working in my application. How can I go about fetching fields such as 'givenname' or 'surname' from the LDAP store and storing them in an SQL database?

Additionally, is it also possible to authorise users only if the LDAP 'uid' matches the 'uid' stored in the local database?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It **IS POSSIBLE** but what happens if someone changes their name? Will you also maintain the database? Why bother when you can just query LDAP each time?

Comment: That is true, but let's just say I'm using the uid, which is a constant field. I will be maintaining the database to add users. The thing is, I'm trying to assign access to specific users by matching their uid against the local database. These users are not in specified groups, so that's where the problem starts.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use SQL Server itself, you can setup a [**Linked Server**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx)

**NOTE:** the default max rows you can return this way is 1000, so always try to restrict you search when possible.

### Adding a Linked Server

You can execute the below sql stored procs to add the Linked Server, be sure to replace @rmtuser and @rmtpassword fields on the second statement with valid login infomation:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver 
    @server = N'ADSI', 
    @srvproduct=N'Active Directory Services 2.5', 
    @provider=N'ADsDSOObject', 
    @datasrc=N'adsdatasource', 
    @provstr=N'ADSDSOObject'

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin
    @rmtsrvname=N'ADSI',
    @useself=N'False',
    @locallogin=NULL,
    @rmtuser=N'DOMAIN\login',
    @rmtpassword='password'
```

### Selecting LDAP Data

You can then use the [**OPENQUERY**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx) function to query LDAP an example:

```
SELECT distinguishedName, sAMAccountName, objectGUID, objectSid, givenName, sn
FROM OPENQUERY(ADSI, 
    'SELECT sn, givenName, objectSid, objectGUID, sAMAccountName, distinguishedName FROM ''LDAP://DC=domain,DC=net'' WHERE objectClass=''User'' AND sAMAccountName = ''nouptime'''
    )
AS derivedtbl_1
```

**NOTE:** the select statement within [**OPENQUERY**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx) must be one continuous line with no line breaks, otherwise it throws an error.

#### LDAP Server Address

The ''LDAP://'' part is constructed if your domain dns address (can be found with command prompt: **ipconfig** under "Connection-specific DNS Suffix") is **corp.domain.net** then it is **''LDAP://DC=corp,DC=domain,DC=net''** or just **domain.net** is **''LDAP://DC=domain,DC=net''**

#### Finding Fields To Select

If you were to use the all column operator (*) in the select statement above you would get all possible fields for a **objectClass** of **User** you can do the same for **Groups** and such to discover which fields you need to return, field name are case sensitive.

**objectSid** is the field I suspect you want, this can be stored in SQL Server as a varbinary(256).

### Filtering LDAP Data

You can also check the state of the account by using the **userAccountControl** field ([**list of values**](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305144)) which is a bitwise field you can do a bitwise check within the [**OPENQUERY**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx) function using the [**LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_BIT_OR**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223367.aspx) which is **1.2.840.113556.1.4.804**, an example using the statement above:

```
SELECT distinguishedName, sAMAccountName, objectGUID, objectSid, givenName, sn
FROM OPENQUERY(ADSI, 
    'SELECT sn, givenName, objectSid, objectGUID, sAMAccountName, distinguishedName FROM ''LDAP://DC=domain,DC=net'' WHERE objectClass=''User'' AND sAMAccountName = ''nouptime''' AND (''''userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.804:''''<>2)
    )
AS derivedtbl_1
```

That statement would return the details of user 'nouptime' as long as the account was not disabled in LDAP.

### Inserting & Updating (Upserting) a Local Cache of LDAP Data

As I am using SQL Server 2008R2 I could use a [**MERGE**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement to update this table in one statement, an example:

```
MERGE INTO tblADUsers
    USING (
        SELECT 
            objectSid, 
            LOWER(sAMAccountName) AS sAMAccountName, 
            givenName, 
            sn,
            LOWER(mail) AS mail,
            CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DateAdded 
        FROM OPENQUERY(ADSI, 'SELECT mail, sn, givenName, sAMAccountName, objectSid FROM ''LDAP://DC=corp,DC=domain,DC=net'' WHERE objectClass=''User'' AND  (''userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.804:''<>2) ')
        AS derivedtbl_1) AS adsoruce
ON tblADUsers.sAMAccountName = adsoruce.sAMAccountName
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET objectSid= adsoruce.objectSid
        ,givenName = adsoruce.givenName
        ,sn = adsoruce.sn
        ,mail = adsoruce.mail
        ,dtUpdated = getdate()
        ,dtDeleted = NULL
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    UPDATE SET dtDeleted = getdate()
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (objectSid, sAMAccountName, givenName, sn, mail, dtDateAdded)
    VALUES (
            adsoruce.objectSid
            ,adsoruce.sAMAccountName
            ,adsoruce.givenName
            ,adsoruce.sn
            ,adsoruce.mail
            ,adsoruce.DateAdded
            )
OUTPUT deleted.*, $action, inserted.*;
```

The **OUTPUT** statement at the end shows you what has been updated/inserted/deleted which you can dump into a table with an **INTO** statement afterwards if you wish to log what is happening. 
I also added date fields so you can see when the user was entered, updated, or deleted. I recommend not deleting rows but just marking it with a deleted date so you don't lose historic users if you remove them from AD after the user leaves the company.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for that detailed example, really appreciate it. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: no problem :) with the rep you gave me I have reformatted and made all links clickable. Hopefully a little clearer.

Comment: Thanks again, your time & effort is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is tagged as C#, but in VB (use a language converter if you need to, telerik is quite good) I would do something such as :

```
Dim dEntry As New DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAPAddress", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD")
Dim dSearcher As New DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher

'You may need to tweek this next line according to your AD forest'
dSearcher = New DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher("(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=user))")
dSearcher.SearchRoot = dEntry
dSearcher.SizeLimit = 1000000

Dim srColl As DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection = dSearcher.FindAll()

For Each result As DirectoryServices.SearchResult In srColl
    Dim resultProperties As DirectoryServices.ResultPropertyCollection = result.Properties

    'Use watch to get the details you need from AD in the resultProperties object'

     'FOR AD GUID'
     Dim ADGuid As String = ""
     If resultProperties.Contains("objectguid") Then
         Dim _byte As Byte() = resultProperties("objectguid").Item(0)
         ADGuid = New Guid(_byte).ToString
     End If

Next
```

The LDAPAddress looks something like `"LDAP://OU=WWWW,OU=XXXX,DC=YYYY,DC=ZZZZ"`

Comment: Great, thanks for that. How do I then store the string in a database or display it on a page? Sorry but I'm still new to C#.

Comment: @nouptime Unfortunately, it would take me a long time to write a database tutorial and that's not what this site is about. I assume you are in a corporation of some kind as you are using AD so you probably have databases already setup. There are plenty of tutorials online for interacting with databases - try googling "c# database tutorial"

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. I've already found some resources that should help. Sorry if it seemed like I was expecting a whole tutorial. Anyway, thanks for the earlier bit of code and pointing me in the right direction.